# How to get out of a select in PostgreSQL without exiting to the terminal?

Tags: postgresql, psql

As you see in the image I have listed all the tables in a database... [image]

I can move up and down, but how can I get back to the postgres prompt? If I use CONTROL+X it takes me back to the linux prompt, but out of postgres.

Thank you ALL for your patience with non-programmers!

Comment: press `q` to quit your pager, which is probably `less`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `less` pager, simply type <kbd>q</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

> If the environment variable PAGER is set, the output is piped to the
>   specified program. Otherwise a platform-dependent default (such as
>   more) is used

so If you are on linux and did not explicitely change `PAGER`, tap `q`

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/more.1.html

> Press space to continue, 'q' to quit.